# Need to generate PK value programatically in multi-threaded application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key

Suppose We create a table, with identity disabled:

```
CREATE TABLE TestIdentity (
    Id    int NOT NULL,
    abc   varchar(10) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ident_test PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
);
```

Note : I have no rights to make Primary Key to identity-enabled, so I have to calculate next Id value from the application programme.

Suppose from multiple connections data is inserted in this table, Id field value is generated by C# application code, the problem is in multi-threaded application 
multiple requests might generate the same id to insert row. In that case SQL server, PK constraint violates.

What is the best solution to reduce PK constraint violation?

Comment: Are you limited on number of requests to the table? E.g. Create ID and then check if it is unique, if not - create a new one. Any forward looking logic will need check for existing key. How uniqueness is checked/enforced now?

Comment: How about using a `uniqueidentifier` as the primary key?

Comment: @Stoleg, In my case logic is, First programme gets max Id of that table and increment it by 1 and use this Id to insert the column, I can achieve this by enabling Identity insert but in my case, I can't do that because the application is very old.
It may possible that multiple threads generate the same Id simultaneously, and I need to avoid that situation at SQL server level e.g SQL server reserve one id for future insertion use.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I can't do that because I need to implement this solution in the legacy application in which data type is int and I need it to be int.

Comment: What parts of this legacy application can you do something about?

Comment: If you are able to create OTHER database objects, this can be serialized through service broker without taking a huge perf hit and you'll get unique PK values.

Comment: Another option is to create IDs in advance and make application pick next available ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this technique will single thread the inserts into this table, but should guarantee uniqueness.  Your C# code would need to do the following in a transaction.  Select the current max Id and hold the lock so other users will wait.  Add +1 to the Id and insert that row.  Commit the transaction

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
select @Id = max(Id) from TestIdentity WITH (TABLOCKX,HOLDLOCK)
set @Id += 1
insert into TestIdentity... new row...
COMMIT
```

Comment: I guess the only problem with this is that it'll be a bottleneck, depending on what other work the application does before it insets the new row

Comment: Agreed - it could be problematic if you have extremely high numbers of inserts going on at the same time, but the select and subsequent insert should be relatively quick - you'd have to test, of course

Comment: @Phil The only way to absolutely eliminate bottlenecks from two threads trying to write at the same time is to have them write to different physical locations (e.g. table per thread or partition per thread). You'll still have log bottleneck of course.

Comment: @ScottHodgin Your answer is useful for me and it is the thing for which I am looking , I just want you to know that, I have just tested your solution and came to know that even without HOLDLOCK this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each thread has a unique identifer I from 1 to N. Generate your PK in the usual way. Then multiply it by 10 and add I. This way, keys generated by thread #1 will always have a 1 as their last digit.

*This assumes there will always be <10 threads, but if N > 10 you can multiply by 100, then add I, by 1000 if N > 100, etc etc.